# Android Toolbar with Avatar and Name clickable

Tags: android, android-actionbar, toolbar

I am looking for a way to create a Toolbar likes a lot of apps with name and a photo.

I need to allow touch, if user touchs the area near the name or the image it will change activity.

Example:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to put the `ImageView` and `TextView` inside your `Toolbar`, he is just a `ViewGroup`. For example:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height_material">

    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearlayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/your_image_description"
            android:src="@drawable/your_image"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/your_string" />

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

After that, you can set the click event on your activity:

```
    LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearlayout);
    linearLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "teste", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

Run on the emulator to see the result:

[image: example running on nexus 5]

Hope this helps.